# Spring Boot Log initialization with Spring Cloud Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Spring Boot 2.2.6-RELEASE

In my `application.yml`, I have this line :

```
logging.config: classpath:my-logback-config.xml
```

This works well, spring get its config nicely

In my `my-logback-config.xml` I have this line :

```
<springProperty name="LOG_HOST" source="config.logHost" />
<springProperty name="LOG_PORT" source="config.logPort" />
```

Again, this works well, it get its value from an external config file, which is defined in a ENV variable

```
SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION=file:/my-env.properties
```

But when I enable Spring Cloud Kubernetes, this fails, with an UnknowHostException : `"LOG_HOST_IS_UNDEFINED" cannot be resolved.` (the value of `LOG_HOST` is used to setup a network appender)

Why does enabling Spring Cloud Kubernetes change the behavior of logging initialization?

It seem that values from SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION are not loaded yet.

I can't load this value from a configMap, since Spring Cloud Kubernetes has not been initialized at the moment logging is being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was that the ENV var `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION` was set to a folder, and not to a file on container.

Locally, on windows, setting 'SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION' to either a file or a folder seems to work, but in the Docker image (RH linux), it has an impact.

When `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION` is set to a folder, values of the enclosed ".properties" files are ignored.

I can reproduce (fix) the issue by changing my docker file :

```
ENV SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION="/mnt/properties/application.properties"
```

to

```
ENV SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION="/mnt/properties/"
```